# Need help managing disks

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, storage, media

I have 4 drives in my laptop 2 ssd and 2 nvme. For some reason I'm getting "ghost" drives showing up in my system and it's throwing everything off. Here's what my /mnt/ looks like:

```
ls /mnt/
'Linux SanDisk St'  'Linux Storage'   Pictures   Storage
```

`Pictures` and `'Linux Storage'` are labels for the same drive that was formatted already twice. I renamed it to `'Linux SanDisk St'` as Ext4 file system. This is where it gets confusing for me. Why are the old labels still showing up in my system? Also my other drive labeled `Storage` is an NTFS file system that doesn't allow me to write any data, but I have w/r permissions.

```
ls -al /mnt/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 user user 4096 Jul 14 03:29  .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Jun  2 11:24  ..
drwx------  3 user user 4096 Jul 13 14:43 'Linux SanDisk St'
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  3 19:42 'Linux Storage'
drwxr-xr-x  2 user user 4096 Jun  2 11:35  Pictures
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 4096 Jul  3 21:46  Storage
```

Would appreciate any help with this. I'm not sure how to fix it, thank you.

This is what `Storage` looks like in Disks.

[image]

Comment: I used Disks to format the drives and mount. I commented out the old disk/label in ``/etc/fstab`` and did ``mount -a``, but I'm still seeing all the same stuff.

Comment: thank you I removed them. I still don't understand why I'm not able to write to ``Storage``? I use windows on the same computer and ``Storage`` is a shared drive between windows/linux. Is it possible that windows locks it some how?

Comment: I already have fast boot turned off in bios. @user68186

Comment: @user68186 Yes, that fixed it. Now I have to do that on my other system too, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Folders not *Labels*

The `ls` command shows the names of directories (also called folders) and files. Partitions are mounted at `mountpoints` which are empty folders. It looks like you have changed the `mountpoints` a few times using the `disks` app.

By doing this you have created a number of sub-directories inside the directory `/mnt`. When no partitions are mounted to these sub-directories, they should be empty. If you don't intend to use them, you can just delete these directories. For example, open a terminal using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo rmdir /mnt/Pictures
```

This will remove the empty sub-directory `Pictures`.

## NTFS Read Only

Windows 10 does not fully shutdown the system by default. It uses "Fast Startup" which is another name for hibernate. This puts a "dirty" flag in the NTFS partitions and Ubuntu opens them in the "read only" mode for safety of the partition.

See [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation) for more.

To stop this you will need to disable Fast Startup. The answers in the above link explains how to do this. [Here is another page on how to do this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup).

Hope this helps